# Timing of adverb after conditional

Tags: adverbs, conditionals, time

The sentence in question:

- Should you decide to decline the offer, the contract is terminated effective immediately.

My question is about the timing of the word immediately.  Would immediately refer to the date of the letter containing the sentence, or the date of the declination of the offer?

Comment: If it was the date of the letter it would already be terminated.  The contract is terminated when you decide to decline and pragmatically, they can’t terminate it as soon as you decide but only as soon as they find out you’ve decided.

Comment: @Jim - what about employment?

Comment: Sorry, really sorry, but if you decline an *offer*, you generally speaking have not yet signed a contract. My comment is about the validity of the proposition...

Answer (score 1):

The sentence doesn't really make sense as given; the main verb needs to be in the future tense:

> Should you decide to decline the offer, the contract will be terminated effective immediately.

Obviously this refers to the (future) time when the offer is declined.